# How to modify the Activity intent in the AndroidManifest so it runs my App.js instead of activity_main.xml

Tags: javascript, android, xml, react-native, android-studio

This is my manifest

```js
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want it to open my app/App.js file instead. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I was using EXPO and it has its own way of building apps. Android studio and expo aren't supposed to work together.

Thank you everyone for not saying anything about this and simply downposting. If anyone needs to know [how to build standalone apps with expo](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/), here's the link.